# How can insert Cutout sign ( ' ) sqlite database from a txt file

Tags: sqlite, display-cutouts

I used sqlite database to save my data. I backuped sqlite table to a txt file. When I try to restore from txt to sqlite I get syntax error (code-1) . Because I used cutout sign `( ' )` for example when I writing (Türk'ler geldi).

Error is :   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ler": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: .......

How can I insert it. I used `( \' )` but it didn't work.

Here is my code from sqlite to txt file

```java
semptoms = db.allSemptom();
int say = semptoms.size();
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("");
  for (int i = 0; i < say; i++) {
Semptom semptom = semptoms.get(i);
String name = semptom.getName();
message.append(name + "\n"); 
  }
saveToSymptom(message.toString());
```

I try to add `.replace(" ' "," \ ' ")` but didn't work

I mean like this

```java
message.append(name.replace(" ' "," \ ' ") + "\n")
```

Comment: You need to use 2 single quotes (not a double quote): `''`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for me. I add  .replace( " ' ",   " '   ' " )

Comment: Good news......

Comment: How can I replace new line for my code. I add for new line   .replace ( " \n " ,   "   |  " ) .  Is there any better solution for new line?

Comment: Doesn't it work?

Comment: It works. But when I restore from txt to sqlite I must add .replace ( "|", "\n") which is opposite of first replace code. I asked because maybe more good solition is posible. In your first answer I don't need to add .replace(" ' ' ", " ' ") [ which is opposite of first replace code] when I restore from txt to sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to forpas for this answer
I used the below code and now problem solved. 
`message.append(name.replace("'","''") + "\n")`
as forpas said in comment